# Error signing apk after moving to JDK 1.8 and SDK 25

Tags: android, java-8, apk, sha

In order to add some new features to our app, we had to upgrade to SDK & Build-Tools 25 which also require updating to JDK 1.8. After upgrading, we can no longer sign our APK, we get the following error:

The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size

Now we can correct this by creating a new key but that means that we can no longer update our APK in the store. Is there a better workaround? It seems like a lot of people are going to hit this sometime soon.

Comment: Technically it would be possible to create a new certificate with a SHA-256 hash using the same private key. Unfortunately according to the Google documentation the whole certificate must be the same, not only the public key and the certificate signature.